# For a single company listed in multiple exchanges in different countries, are the shares being offered the same?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

For a given company ABC, which is listed in PSE, DEU and ASX. Are the shares being offered in DEU the same shares being offered in ASX and PSE? What's the difference if a person buys it in DEU versus if he buys it in ASX?

Apologies in advance, as I do not have an official/full background on stock trading markets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

There are two primary ways to do this.

The first is known as "cross listing". Basically, this means that shares are listed in the home country are the primary shares, but are also traded on secondary markets using mechanisms like ADRs or Globally Registered Shares. Examples of this method include Vodafone and Research in Motion.

The second is "dual listing". This is when two corporations that function as a single business are listed in multiple places. Examples of this include Royal Dutch Shell and Unilever. Usually companies choose this method for tax purposes when they merge or acquire an international company.

Generally speaking, you can safely buy shares in whichever market makes sense to you.

Comment: And makes sense for tax e in the UK You Buy the B version of Royal Dutch Shell (RDSB and not RDSA) to avoid double taxation of dividends